# Error while running an exe compiled with PKG

Tags: javascript, compilation

im compiling a file with PKG. But whenever I try to run the file it gives this error.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh1RL.png)
All versions are up to date.

I'm trying to run my simple javascript code on another computer and this error pops up.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\snapshot\highu\OneDrive\Masaüstü\XXX\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\napi-v6-win32-unknown-x64\node_sqlite3.node'
Require stack:
- C:\snapshot\highu\OneDrive\Masaüstü\XXX\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3-binding.js
- C:\snapshot\highu\OneDrive\Masaüstü\XXX\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3.js
- C:\snapshot\highu\OneDrive\Masaüstü\XXX\.\.\.\.\.js
1) If you want to compile the package/file into executable, please pay attention to compilation warnings and specify a literal in 'require' call. 2) If you don't want to compile the package/file into executable and want to 'require' it from filesystem (likely plugin), specify an absolute path in 'require' call using process.cwd() or process.execPath.
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:946:15)
    at Function._resolveFilename (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1955:46)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:787:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1012:19)
    at Module.require (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1855:31)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\snapshot\highu\OneDrive\Masaüstü\XXX\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\sqlite3-binding.js:4:17)
    at Module._compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1930:22)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1166:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:988:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\snapshot\\highu\\OneDrive\\Masaüstü\\XXX\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\sqlite3-binding.js',
    'C:\\snapshot\\highu\\OneDrive\\Masaüstü\\XXX\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\sqlite3.js',
    'C:\\snapshot\\highu\\OneDrive\\Masaüstü\\XXX\\.\\.\\.\\.\\.js'
  ],
  pkg: true
}

Node.js v18.5.0
```

Comment: Please post your error output as text not a picture. You will get better results.